# How to find the oil concentration of the resulting mixture?

Tags: ratio

> **Question**
>
> Two cans of oil cost Rs. $75$/litre and Rs. $60$/litre for oils of $80\%$ and $40\%$ concentration. When they are mixed in a  certain proportion, the resulting can of oil costs Rs. $56.25$.
>
> Find the oil concentration of the resulting mixture.

Cost of oil in first can = $75\times 80/100 = 60$

Cost of oil in second can = $60\times 40/100 = 24$

Is this correct way to proceed this question?

Comment: This question looks wrong. The cost of the resulting can must be between $60$ and $75$.  I don't see how you can make a can cheaper than $60$...

Comment: Yes even i have this doubt